# Can't install gnome shell extension "places-menu"

Tags: 14.04, gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I seem to have an issue with one specific extension from the GNOME Shell Extensions website. The extension is called Places Status Indicator. I had it installed and working fine, but after rebooting it seems to be completely removed, as it is not listed in GNOME Tweak Tools. Checking my extensions via `gsettings get org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions` however gives me this:

> ['apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com', 'places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com', 'dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com', 'battery_status@milliburn.github.com', 'refresh-wifi@kgshank.net', 'AdvancedVolumeMixer@harry.karvonen.gmail.com', 'disconnect-wifi@kgshank.net', 'Flash_Fullscreen_Fix@fifi.org', 'hibernate-status@dromi', 'ShellTile@emasab.it', 'show-desktop@l300lvl.tk']

So places-menu is still listed. When I try to reinstall it from the website the button just keep switching back to "off" after I click on the install button in the dialogue box. Trying to set it witch `gsettings set org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions` gives me this:

> (gnome-shell:14007): Gjs-WARNING **: JS ERROR: Could not load extension places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions: Error: Missing metadata.json
>   createExtensionObject@/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/misc/extensionUtils.js:100
>   ExtensionFinder<._loadExtension@/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/misc/extensionUtils.js:169

I'm running Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 with GNOME version 3.10.4. I'm still really unfamiliar with Linux, so can anybody tell me what to do now?

Thanks in advance, xorzag.

Comment: Please [edit] this question to replace `witch` with  `which` and remove the sign-off `Thanks in advance, xorzag.`